# Position absolute TD leaves empty space after making visible

Tags: jquery, html, css

So, I have a table and the last TD element in each TR has the class 'abs'. This class has the style as given in the code.

It's hidden by default and on hover of the TR, I show it by giving 'display:block' style to it in jQuery.

```js
$("tr").hover(function() {
  $(this).find(".abs").show();
},
function() {
  $(this).find(".abs").hide();
});
```

```css
.abs {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: -40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<br /><br /><br /><br />
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td class="abs">456</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The problem I have is when the TD.abs is shown (on hover), it displays fine but an empty space appears at the end of the TR which I don't want. This happens only in Chrome, while on Firefox it works fine (empty space not shown).

How do I fix it for Chrome?

Comment: Why would you want to absolutely position a table cell? The content of the cell maybe, but the cell itself?

Comment: created a code snippet based on the code you have provided. Now tell us what are. i cannot see any code written for hover. please add all your code

Comment: @XenioGracias Sorry, I have added the jQuery code for hover now.

Comment: @Andreas That is because I want the last TD to be invisible. If I do the same to a DIV in the TD, then the empty space is always seen. When now the empty space is seen only on hover.

Comment: Your code is working. The `456` is appearing off the bounds of the screen due to `margin-top: -40px;`. I edited the snippet so that the table appears lower down the page and the `'456'` is notw visible. As such there is no issue here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `position: absolute;` and your code will work.

```js
$("tr").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".abs").show();
  },
  function() {
    $(this).find(".abs").hide();
  });
```

```css
.abs {
  display: none;
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: -40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td class='abs'>456</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The code works as it is. The `456` was simply being shown off screen due to the `margin-top: -40px`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That's the thing. It works on Firefox but not this stupid Chrome.

Comment: @SaeeshTendulkar I am testing in Chrome. I edited your question to show the code works fine. Please check that snippet.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Oh yeah, just checked it works on this code. Actually the code which I have is a lot complicated and it doesn't work on that. I tried but can't replicate it for a simple code. Can you just work it out what the problem might be... or the optimal way to do this?

Comment: @SaeeshTendulkar you can remove `margin-top` if will have no impact since we removed position

Comment: @SaeeshTendulkar without seeing the code causing the problem any potential solutions would be a guess, and therefore pointless. Please edit the question to include a more accurate example of the problem